# MySQL uniqueness across multiple fields

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am developing an app that needs to match people together. Each person can only match with one other person.. So, in the table below I am trying to make it so that values from user1 & user2 are unique across both fields:

```
CREATE TABLE `match_table` (
    `user1` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `user2` int(11) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `user2` (`user2`),
UNIQUE KEY `user1` (`user1`))
```

So for example the following INSERT statement should ignore rows 2 and 4. Or at a minimum I need to be able to flag those rows to be ignored. Note that line 5 is OK because of the fact that line 2 and 4 have been ignored.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO match_table (user1, user2)
VALUES
    (1,2),
    (2,3),
    (4,5),
    (6,4),
    (3,6)
```

Is there any index that can accomplish this? .. Otherwise is there some UPDATE I could do after insertion that could flag the ones I want to ignore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the matching has no direction, you can use your existing table design but store the match both ways in the table:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO match_table (user1, user2)
VALUES
(1,2),
(2,1),
(2,3),
(3,2),
(4,5),
(5,4),
(6,4),
(4,6),
(3,6),
(6,3)
```

If you just fetch all rows you will got each matching twice. You can avoid this as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM match_table WHERE user1 < user2
1, 2
3, 6
4, 5
```

One potential issue with this design is that it is possible to insert a row with a user who matches himself.

Comment: Mark.. Thank you.. You are a genius. The answer is quite simple!!

Comment: @Jesse: I and someone else upvoted your question so you have 11 rep now. You need just one more upvote... :)

Comment: Thanks... this site is incredibly easy to get started with, it seems. BTW, I won't be inserting any row with a user that matches himself, no worries there.. and as this is just a temporary table the user1 < user2 trick will work fine. thanks again. I was struggling with super complex UPDATES that were just not working. lol.

Comment: @Mark: I just realized I now have to figure out how to do an insert "both ways". As I am selecting this data from another table I don't see an obvious way to insert two rows for every one row.. with the second row having the values reversed.

Comment: Well, I figured it out I can select the data twice and then do a UNION and then ORDER BY a 3rd primary id column

Answer (score 0):

If you are just asking for a database constraint, you can get that with UNIQUE INDEX ('user1','user2')